# How do I change my pacman root so that it downloads packages elsewhere?

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

My `/root` is full to the brim and I can't install new packages. My `/home` has 8 times the space of my `/root`, but pacman is set to install new packages on `/root`. Is there a safe way that I can change where pacman permanently installs new packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no *safe* way to do this in the long term. From the manual:

> -r, --root 
>            Specify an alternative installation root (default is /). This should not be used as a way to install software into /usr/local
>            instead of /usr. This option is used if you want to install a package on a temporary mounted partition that is "owned" by
>            another system.  NOTE: if database path or logfile are not specified on either the command line or in pacman.conf(5), their
>            default location will be inside this root path.

This is **not** a permanent solution. You need to backup your data and resize your partitions.

You could also clean pacman's cache (`-Scc`) to free up some space in the short term.

Comment: Thanks. I already cleaned the cache and it didn't clear up much space. I suppose I'll back up and repartition. Thanks!

Comment: @JoshieSimmons One of the benefits of using LVM: painless resizing...

Comment: I take it I would have to reinstall Arch to benefit from LVM?

Comment: @JoshieSimmons Yes. The upside is you could enable full disk encryption as well :)