# Arch linux install package to external media

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman

This applies directly to arch linux, but is also relevant for some other linuxes/unices.

I want to install a package. Let's call this package `leviathan`. My harddrive is not large enough to store all of `leviathan`s dependencies. I have an external hard drive that has enough space for `leviathan`. How can I install `leviathan` to that hard drive? Example of what I hope is possible: `sudo pacman -S leviathan -o /media/big/drive` to install it there, but allow me to run it anywhere with `/media/big/drive/leviathan arg1 arg2 arg3`. I don't need or want any of the usual bindings and linkings that a package install creates. I know that this particular package is also attainable as a self-installing bash script, but I tried

Is this possible? If so how so?

NOTE: I have tried to install it by cloning the appropriate URL and building, but it tries to put a bunch of things in weird places. In particular I am trying to install Unity3D on a laptop with <10GB memory available, but with a 2TB hard drive (ext4 formatted) that I use for all of my big things. So if there is no general solution, a unity specific solution would temporarily be acceptable.

Comment: Nope. Make some room on `/` See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122672/how-do-i-change-my-pacman-root-so-that-it-downloads-packages-elsewhere

Comment: Actually, that link seems almost perfect, I just don't have a `/var/lib/pacman/` on my external drive. What is the minimal setup I need there? I don't need a full arch install, but I am happy to have a lot (this external drive already has a number of non-dependent stand-alones on it)

Comment: You don't understand: this won't work...

Comment: I do understand. I just got it working. I set up a LFS-style basic linux file system on my external, (enough that `chroot /media/my/usb` actually worked) then `pacman -S -r /media/my/usb` worked like a charm. As that link suggests, that is the whole point of the `-r` flag.

Comment: Re-read the `man` page: it *explicitly* warns against doing this. But, it is your system, do whatever you want.

Comment: `This option is used if you want to install a package on a temporarily mounted partition that is "owned" by another system."` Even if that system isn't running, my usb *can* be its own system. Why not install there, then run off of it? I don't see a problem...

Comment: Because the USB isn't a system; it is just a drive with that package on it. If leviathan is *completely* self-contained, you will get away with it. If there are any dependencies required by your real system, then the first time they are updated you will discover why it is warned against.

Comment: Oh, right... the dependencies. For some reason I thought that the `-r` option would make it self-contained, and I know nothing depends on it, but I realize that it will depend on some of the things on my main system. I guess I have to always chroot to my device to run the app safely, so it can have the dependencies it wants. I wish unity would just maintain an up-to-date standalone shell script. Oh well. Thanks anyways. :)